# Integration problem with square root

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\int_0^{4/a} e^{\sqrt{ax}}\, d \sqrt{x}
$$

The main problem is the limit. Is it referring to $x$ or $\sqrt{x}$? My English is not good, I am trying my best. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your understanding of $\text d\sqrt x$?

Comment: d√x is a differential. I think it refers to the variable which is supposed to be integrated.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate $$\lim_{a\to +\infty} \int_0^{\frac{4}{a}}\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt a t} \, \mathrm{d} t ?$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $u=\sqrt{x}\to du = d\sqrt{x}$. Upper extreme changes to $u=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}$

The given  integral is equivalent to the following

$$\int_0^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}} e^{u\sqrt{a}} \, du=\frac{e^2-1}{\sqrt{a}}$$